# Get the URL with Angular Router

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router, angular8

I need to fetch my current route (using the Router) in a component (my Nav component) which is located in the App Component but as it's already loaded, it's not refreshing on a click and my function in the nav component isn't returning any new URL.
How can I manage to have the new URL with my nav component ?

Here is my app component :

```html
<app-nav></app-nav>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my nav component (.ts) :

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router.url);
    if(this.router.url == "/") {
      this.color = "large";
      this.logoPath = "assets/logos/w-logo-full.png";
    } else {
      this.color = "small";
      this.logoPath = "assets/logos/c-logo-full.png";
    }
```

It was working when my app-nav was in every component but it's not working anylonger since I've moved it..

Comment: Your NavComponent it's not included in your routes, so you can't get the current route, I advise you to get the current root in the app.component and pass it as a param to the Navbar

Comment: If I move my ngOnInit into nav.component.ts, same issue : on page change, no new URL returned..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use router service events observable

*app.component*

```
  constructor( public router: Router,) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {


      if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(this.router.url);
        // ... 
      }

    });
  }
```

> **NavigationEnd** An event triggered when a navigation ends successfully.

Comment: Working with .events but got a Reference Error on NavigationEnd : NavigationEnd is not defined

Comment: @GermainWeb did add import statement ` import { NavigationEnd, NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: You nailed it !

Answer (score 2):

You need subscribe ActivatedRoute service

something like this:
Add ActivatedRoute:

```
 constructor(
        protected route: ActivatedRoute,
        ...) {
   }
```

Add add subscribe :

```
this.route.url.subscribe(value => {
     ....
    });
```

Comment: In my app component or nav one ?

Comment: @GermainWeb You need add the subscriber where do you want run the if. I guess  in nav component.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
  ActivatedRoute
} from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log("current route is " + route);
  }
}
```